# D3 Treemap with plotts

Tags: d3.js, plot, treemap

I have struggle in a while with my chart but don't understand why is not working.

I want tree map where parents are the block and within these block I want to show dots with the text of birthdate. 
The birthdate I want to connect with the second x Axis at the bottom.

I cant see what I'm doing wrong, been looking for hours now.

My files with htm and json are shared on the following link

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t0x7gdyejb1hj9g/oUZcYmN5EQ

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do -- you seem to be mixing a number of different things. Do you maybe have a picture that shows what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Lars,

It's true that I mix a lot of things :-). I want to mix a plotter chart with a treemap. I do not want to show the children as blocks in the treemap, I want them as plots. I uploaded a picture in my shared dropbox since I not could post it here.

Comment: Hmm, that makes it quite a broad question. I'm not aware of any examples like this.

Comment: I have not found any example either. I think that my x1 axis that I connect to birthdate not working properly. I'm thinking about changing my data model and get some kind of starting date of the parent then I don't need two x-axis but just changing from rectangles to circle when I draw a child